# Using Django/python to JSON posts

Tags: python, json, django

I'm new to using Django so please forgive my ignorance with such a general question. How would you go about displaying JSON posts from a python script? I have a python script which updates an sqlite3 database and creates a JSON object. I want to display this data on a Django frontend. Bonus points if you can give advice on how to make it live update as the database is updated. Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: `json.dumps`? + `websocketio` ? might be worth looking into or angular.js

Answer (score 3):

See Django's [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). Use this in your views.py and return the json as a response in your view.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


...
    return JsonResponse(<your_JSON_object>)
```

Comment: How does Django know where to look for your JSON dumps? The dumps are pointed to a URL so if I'm working locally would the script be pointed to the localhost url the Django app is using?

Comment: Just pass the JSON object that the python script creates to JsonResponse. Then the JsonResponse can pass your JSON object to an ajax function, which can in turn pass that output to a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django Rest Framework.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

I believe that following the tutorial you will be able to create your model's serializer and map it with a suitable view.